# Latex, force 2 images apart

Tags: floats

I have a problem with latex. There is a simple rule i have to follow. No single page can contain ONLY an image. It has to be image + text. Period. My latex keeps putting only an image to a page. What is worse, my sharelatex even forces 2 images to be on the same page which is an even worse no go. How can i tell him to not do that ?

Comment: What `\documentclass` do you use? If you put images in figures, the amount of page that has to be filled with text is set with `\textfraction`, which should be 0.2 by default, unless you implicitly or explicitly changed it.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want float pages (with only images) then do not include `p` in the float placement (or change the default not to include `p`) If you want at most one image per page set

```
\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}
```

Note that if the floats can not be placed according to that constraint and a forced `\clearpage` is reached then all pending floats will be forced on to float pages as an emergency measure.